# Определение падежа "пойти в депутаты"

Tags: морфология

"Пойти в депутаты" - какой падеж?

Answer (score 3):

Падеж винительный. Слово "депутаты" здесь отвечает на вопрос *кого?* (если бы стояло неодушевленное существительное, был бы вопрос *что?*). Эти вопросы, конечно, тут неуместны, но для определения падежа так надо сделать. На вопросы "кого? что?" у нас отвечают существительные в форме винительного падежа.

Answer (score 2):

to Анджей, Замира.
"Пойти в депутаты (рабочие, плотники)" - здесь то же окончание, что и в предложении "Положите тетради в портфели". Т.е. одушевлённое существительное в данном случае "ведёт" себя как неодушевлённое.

Answer (score 1):

Я, конечно, не стану спорить, однако интересно получается... Меня в школе так учили:
именительный падеж - депутаты, родительный - нет кого? - депутатов, дательный - дать кому? - депутатам, винительный - винить кого/что? - депутатов, творительный - творить кем/чем? - депутатами, предложный - говорить о ком/о чём? - (о) депутатах. Но винить кого? - депутаты... Как-то странно. Может быть кто-нибудь сможет мне объяснить в чём тут дело?

Answer (score 1):

Форма "пойти в депутаты" не укладывается в существующую падежную систему. Эти случаи надо рассматривать как особые падежные формы, не имеющие своего названия.

Answer (score 1):

У какого-то автора я видел, что это якобы "второй винительный падеж"

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, замыкаться только на знакомых наборах правил не всегда интересно.

На мой взгляд, гораздо любопытнее  художественные примеры вспомнить:
"Не ходил бы ты, Ванёк, во солдаты!"
"Я б в строители (рабочие, кондукторы) пошёл!"

Answer (score 0):

смысловой вопрос зачем? грамматический во что? падеж винительный.

Answer (score 0):

Это второй винительный падеж. Классификация А.А. Зализняка. 
Спавните: выйти в люди, метить в министры, забрить в солдаты.
По одной из попыток объяснения множественное число здесь приобретает характер собирательности и терят, таким образом, одушевлённость.