# «Баллотироваться в народные депутаты»: падеж

Tags: синтаксис, падежи, управление

Интересно разобраться. По управлению глагола должен быть винительный, но *депутаты* — существительное одушевлённое,  и здесь подходит только именительный.

Насколько понимаю, по каким-то причинам тут происходит переход в категорию неодушевлённых существительных.

Я прав? Если да, то что это за причины в общем случае?

Comment: Этот вопрос ставился: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/364/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b/377#377

Comment: @Alex_ander Да, я видел. Но там очень много сумбура в ответах.

Comment: Да, согласен. Особенно со "вторым винительным" спорно - это термин из другой области, изучающей архаичную грамматику. Jasmin дала хорошую ссылку на большой обзор.

Answer (score 3):

Категория одушевленности-неодушевленности **в предложных сочетаниях** имеет свои особенности, в частности это касается  устойчивых сочетаний с предлогом В.

http://diplomba.ru/work/78770

"Своеобразно проявляется одушевленность-неодушевленность субстантивов в несвободных конструкциях с предлогом в. **В современном русском языке особняком стоят сочетание типа выйти в люди, произвести в офицеры, годиться в матери и под.,** в которых субстантивы, обозначающие людей и животных, имеют грамматический показатель неодушевленности /В.=И./: Кто в кони пошел, тот и вози (Посл.); Барон фон Клоц в министры метил, А я - к нему в зятья (А. Грибоедов); А, Чацкий! Любите вы всех в шуты рядить (Там же); Вот его друг Борис произведен в офицеры, и он из дружбы не хочет отставать от него (Л. Толстой); Работы ни на грош. Ни в гиды, ни в извозчики, Ни в маляры, ни в плотники (А. Черный)."

Answer (score 0):

Jasmin дала хорошую ссылку на обзор толкований ситуации с одушевлённостью/неодушевлённостью. Из того, что там приводится, обращают на себя внимание два разных объяснения:

1. Отход в некоторых случаях от смысловой одушевлённости в направлении некой чисто *грамматической одушевлённости*.
2. Смысловое абстрагирование в сторону неодушевлённости.

Второе мне представляется более убедительным и менее искусственным, и я бы расширил употребление этого толкования на "территорию" первого. Если рассматривать такие случаи как "**в генералы**", "в ферзи", "**в забияки**" и т. п., то здесь можно увидеть *смысловой* уход от одушевлённости: речь идёт о попадании в *абстрактную категорию* (в *сословие* "генералы", в *категорию* "забияки" или в иную - "неодушевлённое" видовое наименование категории опускается, а сама неодушевлённость как бы фиксируется в падежном окончании), а не в реальную группу генералов ("**в генералов**", реально где-то собравшихся, можно *попасть* - напр. выстрелив; "**в забияк**" можно поверить и отпустить их). Соответственно, в данном предложно-падежном сочетании одушевлённость зависит от придаваемого *смысла*.

В других случаях наблюдаются *колебания* в приписываемой одушевлённости, когда микробы, кальмары, креветки могут восприниматься частью носителей языка как неодушевлённые сущности. Для многих в кулинарном смысле кальмары (креветки) - неодушевлённый "морепродукт", и они "*чистят кальмары*" или льют лимонный сок "*в креветки*" или "*на креветки*".